# How to get quantity added to cart on product page which promote to promotion

Tags: magento-1.9, quantity

I wanted to get a way that i could get the quantity if a item that has been added to cart and display in the success message to prompt the user about a promotion. The site i'm working on has Any 3 items for £15.

So if a customer was to order a quantity of 2 for a item, i want something dynamic that looks at the quantity added and in the success page to say order 1 more to get "Any 3 items for £15".

Answer (score 0):

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCount();
```

or if you want qty for every item in cart separately

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $qty = $item->getQty();
}
```